# Cannot invoke ++ with an argument of type int

Tags: swift

Can someone please tell me how I am failing here?

I have a `Struct` called `cardView`, in which I predefine an option called `currentIndex` and define it as an `Integer`.

When I from a function inside my `struct` try to add to `currentIndex` I get a compiler error as the topic says.

Here's how it looks:

```
struct cardView {
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    func addToIndex() {
        currentIndex++
    }
}
```

The `cardView` struct and function is initialized from my `viewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is changing the internal status, so it must be declared as `mutating`:

```
mutating func addToIndex() {
^^^^^^^^
```

Note that this is needed for value types only - classes don't need it, as you can see by just turning the structure into a class.

Answer (score 4):

You can change struct variables from outside of that struct, but not from within its own functions, you need to add the keyword mutating before fun.

```
struct cardView {
var currentIndex: Int = 0
    mutating func addToIndex() {
        currentIndex++
    }
}
```